# C++ : The extraction operator (>>) skips some bytes

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I am trying to write a program that reads a file (an executable in this case) byte by byte, and writes it to a new file that should then be the same.

```
char x;

std::ifstream infile("C:/Users/_user_/Desktop/test.exe", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream outfile("C:/Users/_user_/Desktop/out.exe", std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);

while (infile >> x)
{
    outfile << x;
}

outfile.close();
infile.close();
```

In this example, the out file ends up being 284 bytes shorter.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLTlW.jpg) is a comparison of the 800 first bytes in a hex viewer. The 70th byte of the input file, '09', gets skipped. I am probably missing something obvious, but I can't get my hands on what.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `>>` for binary I/O, use `read` and `write` methods. `operator>>` is designed for formatted input, assumes a stream of text, and is documented to "skip some bytes" (generally, whitespace). `09` happens to be an ASCII code of `\t`, the tab character.

Comment: thank you. How can I see when I reach the end if the file if I use `read` and `write`?

Comment: @RedClaw You can open the file with `std::ios::ate` to open it up at the end. Then you can use `tellg` to get the size of the file, rewind to the beginning and read that amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid skipping whitespace try `put` and `get` for unformatted streams.

```
while (infile.get(x)) {
    outfile.put(x);
}
```